# Git - corrupt loose object on local changes

Tags: git, version-control

I was working on a project locally (I haven't had the time to push to origin) when Ubuntu apparently crashed (all was frozen, I couldn't even move the mouse pointer) forcing me to hard-reboot the computer.

Now when I try to use any of git commands it keeps saying:

```
error: object file .git/objects/5b/44c9bbc189d41c9eff05fdb381ebd2dc83c1e3 is empty
fatal: loose object 5b44c9bbc189d41c9eff05fdb381ebd2dc83c1e3 (stored in .git/objects/5b/44c9bbc189d41c9eff05fdb381ebd2dc83c1e3) is corrupt
```

I have no remote copies of the work I've done.
I was actually working on a local branch named `activity`.

How can I restore it? I don't really want to copy changes over a clean git-repo clone, because it would lose all previous commit messages...

Following similiar posts (also if it doesn't seem to apply to my case) here are some outputs:

```
$ git fsck --full      
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: object file .git/objects/18/c482efa7845af0ab2d2ebc19370ca6645cda68 is empty
fatal: loose object 18c482efa7845af0ab2d2ebc19370ca6645cda68 (stored in .git/objects/18/c482efa7845af0ab2d2ebc19370ca6645cda68) is corrupt
```

I also ran ls-tree with the following (same) output:

```
$ git ls-tree 5b44c9bbc189d41c9eff05fdb381ebd2dc83c1e3        
error: object file .git/objects/5b/44c9bbc189d41c9eff05fdb381ebd2dc83c1e3 is empty
fatal: loose object 5b44c9bbc189d41c9eff05fdb381ebd2dc83c1e3 (stored in .git/objects/5b/44c9bbc189d41c9eff05fdb381ebd2dc83c1e3) is corrupt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just started to work on this repository and your work tree is ok, start a new repo. This time push up a backup to bitbucket which offers free private repositories. Remember to commit often and push up your changes.

```
git show SHA1
```

can also be helpful.

Comment: `git show` returns the same output as listed on the original post.
I do push on a remote origin, but I was working on a local branch, once the feature is complete I'll push to the origin. Is there something I can do to recover today's history? If I just copy files I'll have only the last version... I pushed 7 hours ago on the remote origin...

Comment: You can systematically import into another clone each commit you have.  Run fsck each time. This will point you to which commit is itself corrupted or contains a corrupt tree or a blob. You can also try `git bundle` or a series of `git checkout branch -- .` and make a new branch that you can then export.

Comment: Can you please post the detailed procedure or a link to it? I'm not sure how should I chain commands you listed. I've downloaded another clone of the origin, named "agenda2", while the corrupted one is named "agenda".

Comment: make another branch. point it to one of the oldest commits. see if you can push that branch up to a remote. In fact, you may be able to use `git bisect` for this..